Access Network Share via Dynamic IPV6
I have a shared printer at home which has a dynamic ipv6. I can access it via \\<ipv6 address>.ipv6-literal.net. But if my ipv6 change, I have to know the new ipv6 and change the ipv6 of the printer to access it again. Is there any way that the ipv6 address can be change automatically like no-ip but has a suffix of ipv6-literal.net? Sorry if my English is bad. I have Windows 11

Almost all network printers support local LAN hostnames via mDNS. Search the printer's configuration page for a hostname that looks like <something>.local, then use that name in your Windows configuration.

Problem is, my printer does not have LAN Support. Printer is plugged in using USB to my laptop, and from my laptop, I network share it. So to access my printer, you need to access my laptop local IP address or via IPV6 for outside internet.

Do the same thing then, but with the laptop's computer name instead.

I cannot access using the Laptop's Name from different ISP. Only via ipv6.
